# What is the distance between two consecutive material jetting holes in a series in a polyjet printer?

Tags: polyjet-printer

In a material jetting 3D printer (polyjet printer) there are multiple holes arranged in series and multiple such serieses are arranged in rows. (See image below).  These holes jet the material onto the build platform.
What I want to know is what is the typical distance between two consecutive holes in a series.

[image]

Comment: Do you ask abotu a specific printer? This is printer-model specific!

Comment: @Trish what would be the **typical** distance? I mean between what ranges of disatnce are the holes spaced in most models?

Comment: It depends on the system setup! In **FDM** the lowest achievable distance is "1 perimeter", the smallest reliable one "2 perimeters", where the perimeter is related to the nozzle diameter; for **SLA/DLP** it is "2 pixels", for **SLS** it's "2 laser diameters". Polyjets again are different in setup. I can't find any numbers for any of these machines...